# How to require a user to be logged in

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP an was wondering how I have to make the user login before they can go to any other page on the website. 

For example on www.cyka.us/p/index.php it will redirect them to www.cyka.us/p/login.php

Comment: @meme.please Google it so many tutorials are availble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever used **sessions** in php? You can use **sessions** as a marker if a certain user is logged in or not. It can be implemented like this:

```
$isLogIn = $session('login');
if($isLogIn){
    //go to other webpages
}
```

Search **sessions** for further information :)

Comment: Good luck and have fun programming :)

Answer (score 0):

You simply test for it:

```
if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    http_response_code(403);
    include("p/login.php");
    exit;
}
```

… the specifics of the `user_is_logged_in` function will depend on how you've implemented your login system.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with **sessions** concept in php. For every page you need check whether the user is logged in or not and redirect to (login)desired page.